# Example of function $f\in C^{\infty}$ but not holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

I know that holomorphic function are infinitely differentiable .

I think converse not true .I am searching for counterexample. But I did not get .

Please can anyone suggest me how to find such example.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think $z\mapsto \overline{z}$ is an easy counter. In terms of real it is just $(x,y)\mapsto(x,-y)$

Comment: The trick is that $f(z)=\bar{z}$ is *not* complex differentiable, failing to satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Complex differentiable (even once) implies analytic implies infinitely differentiable.

For (real) infinitely differentiable but not analytic, standard example is $e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$.